# Application Installation error Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, failed-installation

I have an application of mine on AppStore. But one user is complaining that he can not install the application on his device(Curve 8900) and it's giving error

"Error starting AppName
$28NonTouch$29:
Module 'AppName
$28NonTouch$29-2' has
verification errors."

Now how come it is possible that other's users are able to download properly while one user is getting this error. I downloaded the application from the appstore and its working perfectly.

And when this user tries to install the application through Desktop Manager he is getting error

"No additional applications can
be found. Your file may contain applications that already exist in the
application list, are not compatible for your device, or have errors."

When i tried to stimulate the issue here by installing the application through desktop manager i am able to install it properly without any error messages.

Can anyone suggest me ,what might be causing this issue.?? Is there any kind of version mismatch??

My application is compiled usiong jdk 4.5.

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Kindly help,Its urgent..

Thanx in advance."

Comment: Have you tried it on 8900 Simulator ?

Comment: yes, i have installed on simulator as well as on device..

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is related with the version specified in the .alx file.

Check the .alx file and remove the "_blackberryVersion" tag, or change it so it matches the OS version on your device.